# Access Class inside a Class

Tags: vba, excel, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a simple Excel VBA web scraping macro. At one point, I need the macro to click a button (in the enclosed image lower - `button class="edit"`), which is inside a specific `class="title">TitleName`. On the webpage, there are more than one `TitleName`, and I always need to go to a specific `TitleName` and click a `TitleName` specific edit button.

Can someone please help with the macro? The HTML code is in the following image:
[image: Html image]

Comment: Please [edit] your original question and add the VBA code you already have. You might also read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) Then tell what is going wrong in your code and where you got errors or got stuck. Also don't post code as images, instead add the code formatted as code block. Other users cannot do anything with a code image. Also we might need to see a code example with at least 2 different `TitleName`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

Grab the collection of the tagName of `button`, then iterate through them until you find the one with your className of `edit`.

Code:

```
Sub pressBtn()

    'your html declarations & navigation

    'Grab the content class that contains your titlename
    Dim contentClassColl As Object, contentClass As Object
    Set contentClassColl = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("content")

    Dim TitleName As String, pColl As Object, p As Object, exitFlag As Boolean
    TitleName = "YourTitleNameHere"

    'Grab the correct class by looking at each tagname within the class for your title
    For Each contentClass In contentClassColl
        On Error Resume Next 'in case there are no tag name 'P' in class
        Set pColl = contentClass.getElementsByTagName("p")
        For Each p In pColl
            If p.innerHTML Like "*" & TitleName & "*" Then
                exitFlag = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next p
        On Error GoTo 0
        If exitFlag = True Then Exit For
    Next contentClass

    Dim btnColl As IHTMLElementCollection, btn As IHTMLElement
    Set btnColl = contentClass.getElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each btn In btnColl
        If btn.className = "edit" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next btn
    btn.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this doesn't answer the question at all: How are you able to select a specific edit button by `class="title">TitleName` here? This is only an example of how to loop through the buttons and find the edit button (which is just a small part of the original task). Also there are many edit buttons and this code always grabs the first one.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you K.Davis for the code above, but it only selects the first edit button. I need a TitleName specific edit button, if you consider that there are many titles.

Comment: I'll take a look at it

Comment: @Shiwers it's almost impossible to answer that question without seeing the **continuous** HTML code that contains at least 2 different `class="title">TitleName`. Please add this **to your original question** as code not as image. Also add the VBA code you already tired.

Comment: @Shiwers see if that works. If not, more html code will need to be provided.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs it seems like it might work, however, if i try to call the sub, error  "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" appears and .tagName("p") is highlighted... what may be causing this?

Comment: @Shiwers updated it. Maybe there is another class name `content` that doesn't contain a tag of `p`. Also changed it to `getElements...` rather than using that property (I tried to set a property as an object - which is not allowed).